# I want to return a user with a list of all the people they have referred by there username

Tags: laravel

I am developing a referral system in my software. I have gotten the referral right but I want to list all users the auth users have referred.

Note: I am writing an API endpoint so I cant use a relationship to display their name.
Here is my user model

```
public function referrals()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Referral::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}

public function referrer()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Referral::class, 'referred_by', 'id');
}
```

Note: referred_by is the person that has referred someone and user_id is the person referred

Here is my referral model

```
protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'referred_by', 'status'];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Here is my referrals migration

```
Schema::create('referrals', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->integer('referred_by')->unsigned()->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->string('status')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just edit the `user`s table and add `referred_by` and `status`? I'm quite confused by your `referrals` table structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User Model

```
// Referrals given by the user.
public function referralsGiven()
{
    return $this->hasMany(App\Referral::class, 'referred_by', 'id');
}
```

Referral Model

```
//Person who got the referral
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}

public function referredBy()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class, 'referred_by', 'id');
}
```

> pluck collection method https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-pluck

Controller

```
$user = User::with('referralsGiven.user')->find(Auth::user()->id);

$users_reffered_by_Auth_user = $user->referralsGiven->pluck('user');
```

OR

```
$referrals = Referral::with('user')->where('reffered_by', Auth::user()->id)->get();

$users_reffered_by_Auth_user = $referrals->pluck('user');
```